# Selecting values in table1 that are not in table2, then inserting those values into the table2 gives PRIMARY KEY constraint error?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select rows from a table that are not in another table based on id matches, then insert those rows into the other table since it does not have them. I'm using this query

```
insert into table2 (key1, key2, key3, some_value1, some_value2)
select t1.key1, t1.key2, t1.key3, some_value1, some_value2
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2
    on t2.key1 = t1.key1 and t2.key2 = t1.key2 and t2.key3 = t1.key3
```

And tried with this one too

```
insert into table2 (key1, key2, key3, some_value1, some_value2)
select t1.key1, t1.key2, t1.key3, some_value1, some_value2
from table1 t1
where not exists (
    select 1
    from table2 t2
    where t2.key1 = t1.key1 and t2.key2 = t1.key2 and t2.key3 = t1.key3
)
```

When I run the query, it gives me an error

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_table2'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'table2'. The duplicate key value is (101278694, 0060, 4PF93LA#ABM).;

But I don't understand, because I selected values that are NOT in table2, yet it sates that I'm trying to insert duplicate values into table2

`key1`, `key2`, and `key3` are primary keys in `table2`, but are regular columns in `table1`

Comment: Show `table1` and `table2` ddl.

Comment: Which one of the query gives the error?

Comment: *key1, key2, and key3 are primary keys in table2, but are regular columns in table1* - it clarifies all. @GordonLinoff solution must fit you.

Comment: Yes, table1 had duplicate data I was trying to insert into table2. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have more than one row in table 1 that has the values (101278694, 0060, 4PF93LA#ABM).  Your query needs some logic to resolve the duplicates.  You could do something like this

```
select t1.key1, t1.key2, t1.key3, max(some_value1), max(some_value2)....
(add group by key1,key2,key3)
```

but maybe max is not what you want.  You could also do something like this which pulls only distinct sets of keys that are not already in t2 and not paired with multiple value1,value2 combinations in t1

```
insert into table2 (key1, key2, key3, some_value1, some_value2)
select distinct t1.key1, t1.key2, t1.key3, some_value1, some_value2
from table1 t1
where not exists (
    select 1
    from table1 t3
    where t3.key1 = t1.key1 and t3.key2 = t1.key2 and t3.key3 = t1.key3 and
         (t3.value1 != t1.value1 or t3.value2 != t1.value2)
) and not exists (
    select 1
    from table2 t2
    where t2.key1 = t1.key1 and t2.key2 = t1.key2 and t2.key3 = t1.key3
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second version seems like it should work . . . unless there are duplicates in the data being inserted.

```
insert into table2 (key1, key2, key3, some_value1, some_value2)
    select t1.key1, t1.key2, t1.key3, some_value1, some_value2
    from (select t1.*,
                  row_number() over (partition by key1, key2, key3) as seqnum
          from table1 t1
         ) t1
    where seqnum = 1 and
          not exists (select 1
                      from table2 t2
                      where t2.key1 = t1.key1 and t2.key2 = t1.key2 and t2.key3 = t1.key3
                     );
```

The `order by` clause is optional in MySQL.  This returns an arbitrary row for each combinations of keys.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing all the field, hence you are getting this PK violation error. You should only compare PK values

Example:

```
TABLE2 1
PK1    COL1_VALUE         COL2_VALUE

TABLE 2
PK1    COL1_OTHER_VALUE   COL2_OTHER VALUE
```

As you can see both table 1 and table 2 has same PK1 value, but column1 and column 2 has different value. So as per your query, table2 row does not exist in table 1, but still PK values are same in both the tables.

So a solution is to check for only PK in `not exist` clause.